# Cognito - Sign up with Email, sign in with preferred username

Tags: authentication, oauth, amazon-cognito

I have a cognito user pool with the `Username - Users can use a username and optionally multiple alternatives to sign up and sign in.` field checked. In addition, I have checked the following:

```
Also allow sign in with verified email address
Also allow sign in with preferred username (a username that your users can change)
```

Now I've got the page with the username displaying just fine, but I can't find a way to sign *up* with an email. My ideal flow would be:

Email signup - mail them a default preferred username.
Then they click a link, and change the preferred username.

It would seem like you must use a username to sign up with the service if you want to use both username and email - is that accurate, or am I missing something here?

To be clear, I want the sign-up/in form to accept either an email or a preferred username (much in the way that Facebook accepts an email or a phone number) and a password. Is this possible?

Comment: Hey @JapanRob, did you find any solution for this? I m also facing the same issue.

Comment: @HackRx sorry for the late response - 
This was a couple years ago for a client that I was freelancing for, and I no longer have the answer with me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked preferred username as required under "Which standard attributes are required?"? If yes, then while signup you have to provide BOTH username and emailID. Since you want a default username when user is signed up you can generate a username (maybe based on email) and pass that to API. After user signs in they can then change their username.

Comment: Username isn't in that field - preferred username is. But, more specifically, my issue is that I would like a sign-up/in field where you could enter either value. I don't see a way to enable that.

Comment: What have you checked in the "required" fields?